# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis, select * from {function}

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to run the following query.
`select * from table(PK_ADMIN_REPORT.FN_GET_APPS_RECIEVED_OFFER(:CATALOG_YEAR IN NUMBER));`
But it says 'ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FN_GET_APPS_RECIEVED_OFFER(:CATALOG_YEAR IN NUMBER)` looks like a [function declaration](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/parameter_declaration.htm#CJAJDGCC); you don't include the direction and type of parameters when they're passed in. So it probably ought to be:

```
select * from table(PK_ADMIN_REPORT.FN_GET_APPS_RECIEVED_OFFER(:CATALOG_YEAR));
```

The ORA-00907 error doesn't necessarily literally mean there is a missing parenthesis, it's often (or usually) indicative of some generic syntax error. In this case it's expecting a closing `)` or a comma immediately after `(:CATALOG_YEAR`, but it's seeing `IN NUMBER` instead *at that point*. It's not the number of parenthesis, it's where they're placed that it's complaining about.